# Pythonic way to replace multiple characters in a string

Tags: python

I am looking for a pythonic way to replace multiple characters in a string.

**For Example:**
"Sault Ste. Marie" to "SaultSteMarie"

I know that I can use the *replace* function here:

```
"Sault Ste. Marie".replace(' ', '').replace('.', '')
```

but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I believe the best you'll find in that regard would use the `re` module: `re.sub(r"[\s.]", "Sault Ste. Marie")`

Comment: @brittenb, you have a little mistake, without second argument: re.sub(r"[\s.]", "", "Sault Ste. Marie")

Comment: @JRazor correct, thank you